# How to scroll a widget from another widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

The right way to interact between widgets in flutter is Provider. But Provider manages a data, but with just scrolling, no data is supposed to be changed. How is it possible to send a scroll command (like jumpTo) between widgets placed on same level? (not like parent\child relation)

For example: there is a button that adds a new item to the ListView with provider like that:

```
listProvider.createItem("New item");
```

And the list should be scrolled down to the end after that.
How to do that?

Comment: Are you using ListView as scrollable widget?

Comment: I create the list in that way: return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController, ...

Answer (score 1):

```
Widget A{

@override build (ctx){
return B(_scrollController) ;

}


Widget B{
ScrollController scrollController;
B{this._scrollController}

}
```

Use this right after `listProvider.createItem("New item")` to scroll to bottom of listview.
`_scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent)`

Comment: Thank you. Is it the only possible way to do that? I mean to share the scrollController between widgets?

Comment: You can past it through Widget's constructor. I'm updating the answer, do check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the scrollController provided to the listView:
You can call `scrollController.position.moveTo(scrollcontroller.position.maxScrollExtent)` after you've added the element to the ListView.

You can also add a duration to moveTo to get to scroll down more naturally.

Edit: you could create a wrapper around ListView that handles that if you want it to happen every time you add something

```
class JumpToAddedObjectList extends ListView {  
  JumpToAddedObjectList(){
    scrollController = new ScrollController();
    listView = new ListView(scrollController:scrollController);
  }

  ScrollController scrollController;
  ListView listView;

  @Override
  void build(Context context){
    return listView;
  }

  @Override
  void add(Object o){
    listView.add(o);
    scrollController
      .position
      .moveTo(scrollcontroller
         .position.maxScrollExtent)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it the only possible way to do that? I mean to share the scrollController between widgets?

Comment: Well kinda, you can wrap ListView if you think that is neater. Added an example.